# QML TextInput signal

Tags: qml, textinput

I've spent a lot of time resolving this without success.
I only need a signal when it's clicked on textInput element. Like onClicked.
Just to let know, this TextInput was selected, or clicked on.

I have more TextInput elements and I only need the current one to emit the signal. I tried to use focus, but the previous element emitted too.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you really need to know when the TextInput is clicked, or do you just need to know when it is focused ?
You could listen to the `activeFocus` property like so : `onActiveFocusChanged: if (activeFocus) { /*do stuff here*/ }`

Answer (score 1):

TextArea does not emit signal when clicked. If you are only interested in clicks, you should add a MouseArea on top. You can set `mouse.accepted` to `false` to let the event bubble, so that TextInput get the click event and processes it. Note you'll get the event in the MouseArea before handling takes place in the TextInput

```
TextInput {
  // ...

  MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    propagateComposedEvents: true

    onClicked: {
      console.log("clicked on TextInput");
      mouse.accepted = false;
    }
  }
}
```